# Top function list menu without mouse

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to get to top menu with function list without mouse? Some short key would be fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about intellisense? If so, ctrl+space is what you need. Anyway, this is not the place for this kind of questions, and clearly not c# specific

Comment: So I start a guess: it's vs2017?

Comment: @Rafalon I _guess_ OP is talking about the combobox containing the members of the current class top-right of the editor window.

Comment: @RenéVogt well ctrl+space usually displays available terms with intellisense, so this could be what he needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> will take you to the dropdowns. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> across to the method dropdown.